# Orgmode +INCLUDE not allowing partial inclusion of files

Tags: emacs, org-mode

As per documentation (http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html#fnd-1) I try to include part of the the file in the following way:

```
#+INCLUDE: "../experiments.org::*Experiments"
```

When running M-x org-publish-curent-project I get an error message

```
Cannot include file "(...)/experiments.org::*Experiments"
```

At the same time an external link works perfectly and points to the proper headline:

```
[[../experiments.org::*Experiments]]
```

My versions:

1. GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.30) of 2017-06-27
2. Org-mode version 8.2.10

Is it a bug? Should I just submit a bug report?

Comment: I believe your org-mode version is too old: the manual describes v9.0.9. You need to upgrade to get this capability

Comment: Thank you, @Nick after I've updated org-mode the described +INCLUDE functionality started working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion of Nick I've updated org-mode to the latest 9.0.9 version and the problem is gone now.